# Why does my Python code work in Jupyter Notebook but not as a script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, imagemagick, wand

I'm trying to open up a PDF as an image using Wand.  If I run the code below in Jupyter Notebook, it works fine.  If I run the code as a script from Command Prompt, I get an error message.  For some reason, the module won't load when it's run outside of Jupyter Notebook.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Windows

Python 3.7.2 (64 bit)

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="C:/test.pdf", resolution=300) as img:
    print(type(img))
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Untitled.py", line 7, in <module>
    from wand.image import Image
  File "C:\Users\spencer.rand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import compat
  File "C:\Users\spencer.rand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wand\compat.py", line 25, in <module>
    abc = collections.abc if PY3 else collections
  File "C:\Users\spencer.rand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f'module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}')
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'abc'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's an issue with wand and collections that was fixed 2 weeks ago: https://github.com/emcconville/wand/pull/398

Try updating your wand install: `pip install --upgrade wand`

Comment: Thanks but it looks like I've got the latest version:


Requirement already up-to-date: wand in c:\users\spencer.rand\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.5.1)

Comment: @spencerrand Issue resolved in version 0.5.2, which should be release & distributed by now.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it works in Jupyter notebook but not as a script, but you were both right in getting the script to work.  I upgraded to 0.5.2, which is what Danielle suggested, and that worked.  Thank you @emcconville and Danielle for your help.

Comment: @spencerrand it might that Jupyter notebook has access to a different version within it's environment - that was the guess my answer was based on.